# Getting SensorManager from off-screen fragment is crashing app, NPE

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in my app that currently holds 6 Fragments. I have set off-screen limit appropriately, and haven't had a problem with this until now. In the problematic Fragment, There is a ListView that holds all sensor's name and vendor. When I try to retrieve all of this information into a String, my app crashes. The culprit is this line here 
            `SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);`

this is initialized onActivityCreated, and works well except when trying to get text and strings, it is null.

```
public String retrieveContent() {
    String content = "";

    if (sensorItems == null) {
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List<Sensor> deviceSensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        sensorItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceSensors.size(); i++) {
            SensorListModel sensorListModel = new SensorListModel();
            sensorListModel.name = deviceSensors.get(i).getName();
            sensorListModel.vendor = deviceSensors.get(i).getVendor();
            sensorItems.add(sensorListModel);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < sensorItems.size(); i++) {
        content = content + sensorItems.get(i).retrieveContent();
    }

    return content;
}
```

and my very simple Model if you need to see it.

```
public class SensorListModel {

    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvVendor;
    public String name;
    public String vendor;

    public String retrieveContent() {

        return tvName.getText() + "\n"
                + tvVendor.getText() + "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Everything works fine and the data displays in listview. I don't understand why it crashes when calling `retrieveContent` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not on screen, its view will be destroyed (`onDestroyView()`) and it will be detached from the `Activity` (`onDetach()`). This means that when you call `getActivity()`, the result will be null, as it no longer is attached to an `Activity`.

Just keep a reference to the `SensorManager` in `onAttach()`:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: I load all the Fragments in background onCreate() of app with AsyncTask. Wouldn't this be sufficient?`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7 - 1);` I use the `retrieveContent()` method in 5 other Fragments and haven't had a problem with it until this one. Thank you

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be loading fragments in the background. When views are created they do a lot of internal initialization expecting to be on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well it has something to do with the `Context`, so I added `retrieveContent()` method to my MainActivity holding the Fragments for when the user needs it. No longer retrieving it from the Fragment (even though it has been created before I call this method, causing NPE), and call from main activity.